# How to find objective and constraint function when given just an equation of a line and a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

So here is the question:

[image]

Now, to find any extremum, I need the objective function, f(x,y) and a constraint function, g(x,y),
since the components of gradient f will equal the components of gradient g(x,y) * lambda.

However, given just an equation of a line and a point, I really do not know how to establish my objective function (f) and my constraint function (g).

If someone can explain the steps for finding those two functions I am sure I can solve the problem on my own from there.

Comment: The objective function is clearly verbally stated in the text: "... the minimum distance from the curve ... to the indicated point."

Comment: So, ask yourself, what is the formula for the distance between the given point $(0,2)$ and any point $(x,y)$ on the line?

Comment: Yes. I did that initially. so basically, we know any vector PQ is parallel to a directional vector v. Therefore, I wrote down PQ as <x, (y-2)>

Comment: but that is honestly, as far as I got because nothing really made sense afterwards... so now I have components of a vector PQ along a line L defined by x-y = 6 but then what?

Comment: Clearly there are some preliminary steps I am missing in order to find the objective function, or maybe I am forgetting some earlier concept that defines a curve C given an equation of a line L

Comment: What is the distance of any point $(x,y)$ to point $(0,2)$? This gives you the objective function.

Comment: the distance is magnitude of vector PQ

Comment: PQ = <x-0, y-2>

Comment: So the distance is: square root of (x^2 + (y-2)^2

Comment: Here you go! :-)

Comment: Btw., to make life easier when calculating the derivatives: Instead of minimizing the magnitude of $PQ$, you can minimize the square of this magnitude.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I got two different critical points, (8,2) and (4, -2). Of the two points, (4, -2) is smaller than (8,2) and f(4,-2) = square root(32)

Comment: The answer is correct. But holy cow. At first, this was exactly what I had in mind. The distance between PQ is the magnitude but I didn't know where to go from there. Thank you

Comment: How does your Lagrange function looks like? I got only $1$ critical point $(x_0,y_0,\lambda_0)=(4,-2,8)$.

Comment: Well constraint is x-y=6. Therefore, gradient of fx = (x/square root(x^2+(y-2)^2) = lambda. Then gradient of fy = y-2/(square root(x^2+(y-2)^2)) = - lambda.

Comment: I then set fx = -fy then it simplifies to x = 2-y and i substitute that in for constraint function x-y = 6. which gives me -2y = 4 ----> y = -2

Comment: But I also checked for the case where y = 2, which satisfies the equation x-y = 6, and that gives x=8

Comment: Your method of calculation is ok. Btw., another usual way to set up the Lagrangian here is (minimizing the square of the distance): $L(x,y,\lambda)=x^2+(y-2)^2-\lambda(x-y-6)$. But no need to check the extra point :-)

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized, there was absolutely no need for me to have checked for the case when y=2.. so yeah.. we both got the same answer... f(4, -2) = square root(32)

Comment: You see, you could solve it all on your own. Just some little help here and there. Well done! :-)

Comment: haha and yeah, honestly 90% of the time i have the right concept at first but I keep second-guessing myself. I just need more practice and studying to erase that habit. thanks again man. appreciate it